# Error running a rails project after updating versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm updating Ruby and Rails versions of a project and i'm having this issue trying to run the server. Searching i found that it could be due to incompatible versions, but i found many articles saying that these versions are compatible. I'm updating the Ruby version from 2.6.6 to 3.0.0 and Rails version from 5.2 to 6.0

```
/home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:153:in `new': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:153:in `memoized'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:234:in `<class:ProxyOptions>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:216:in `<module:Faraday>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:80:in `block in require_libs'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:79:in `each'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:79:in `require_libs'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:240:in `<module:Faraday>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:16:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/oauth2-1.4.4/lib/oauth2/client.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/oauth2-1.4.4/lib/oauth2.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.7.1/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.7.1/lib/omniauth-oauth2.rb:2:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2-1.0.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/linkedin.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2-1.0.0/lib/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2.rb:2:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/ProgramaThor/config/application.rb:24:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:141:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/Project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /home/lucca/.bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /home/lucca/Project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'`
```

I've changed the Gemfile, updated bundler, updated Rails and updated Ruby version.

Comment: upgrade `faraday` gem. `v0.9.2` is a decade old.

Comment: you should not need to change the Gemfile, except for the new rails version.... I assume you ran "bundle" right? This should've updated faraday automatically, unless you have fixed the version of faraday in Gemfile. Generally you should not fix versions in Gemfile, let bundler find the compatible version for you.